# Cloud-based music player with offline mode and web version (alternative to YouTube Music)

Tags: android, offline, music, cloud-storage

I'm looking for a music player that checks all of the following boxes, which is basically what the now gone [Google Play Music](https://music.youtube.com/googleplaymusic) did and what also seems to be possible with [YouTube Music](https://music.youtube.com/):

1. ☑️ Your own music saved in the cloud (self-managed such as Google Drive, or managed)
2. ☑️ Android app with offline mode, i.e. possible to download songs to phone to listen when offline
3. ☑️ Web version for listening to music on laptop
4. ☑️ Free for basic usage or one-off payment (no subscription)

The desired use case is quite simple: have a single location in the cloud to manage all your music files, then listen to them on both phone (with possible offline mode) and laptop.

So far I found apps like [CloudBeats](https://www.cloudbeatsapp.com/) or [CloudPlayer](https://www.doubletwist.com/cloudplayer) which check all the boxes above except "web version".

YouTube Music seems to be able to do all of the above with the free version and your own uploaded music. However, YouTube Music has an overly complicated user interface if all you want is to listen to your own music files.

So, is there a simpler alternative that can do all of the above?